# asp.net mvc 4: client validation not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I have a model:

```
public class UserInfoViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("CarNumber", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        [Required]
        public string CarNumber { get; set; }  

        [LocalizedDisplayName("CarMark", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        public string CarMark { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("CarYear", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        [IntLengthAttribute(4, ErrorMessage = "Wrong Year")]
        public int CarYear { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("Email", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("PhoneNumber", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("FullName", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("FirstName", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("LastName", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [LocalizedDisplayName("MiddleName", NameResourceType = typeof(CabinetViewModelsStrings))]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }       

    }
```

When user click `Edit` button I show the dialog:

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit_info', function() {
        var dialog = createDialog();
        var editUrl = '/cabinet/edit';
        dialog.load(editUrl, function(content) {
            dialog.dialog({
                close: function(event, ui) {
                    dialog.remove();
                },
                modal: true,
                width: 460,
                resizable: false
            });
        });
    });
```

The `Edit` view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Cabinet", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { Id = "update_user_info" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@CabinetViewsStrings.FormEditInfo</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MiddleName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MiddleName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CarNumber)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CarNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarNumber)
            </li>                
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CarMark)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CarMark)
            </li>                
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CarYear)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CarYear)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarYear)
            </li>      
        </ol>
        <input id="update_user_info" type="submit" value="@CabinetViewsStrings.ButtonSaveEditInfo" />
    </fieldset>
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

But when I click sumbit button with empty `CarNumber` field I don't get any errors.
Where is a error?

The needed js library are loaded:

```
GET jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js?_=1359182513969
GET jquery.validate.js?_=1359182514123
GET jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?_=1359182514379
```

This part of generated html:

```
<li>
     <label for="CarNumber">Car Number</label>
     <input type="text" value="B650LZN" name="CarNumber" id="CarNumber" data-val-required="The Car Number field is required." data-val="true">
</li>
```

This is actions:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
   var model = _viewModelCreator.Create<UserInfoViewModel, User>(PcpSession.CurrentUser);
   return PartialView(model);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(UserInfoViewModel userInfo)
 {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(userInfo);
    }

    var user = _entityCreator.Create<User, UserInfoViewModel>(userInfo);
    _userService.UpdateUser(user);
    PcpSession.CurrentUser = user;

    return Json(new { });
 }
```

Comment: Does the form completely submit or it just doesn't show the errors?

Comment: Frankly I can't find anything wrong with your code! In the controller when the Edit action receives the model, are you checking ModelState.IsValid? If so is it true or false? Is it possible to show us the Edit action in the controller?

Comment: @BahmanNikkhahan: I added the code of actions

Comment: Did you check my suggestion bellow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think adding [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] before your action(in controller) will solve your problem